# Как повесить посредник на группу маршрутов с префиксом?

Tags: laravel, mvc

**Версия** Laravel: **5.4**.

Имеется группа маршрутов:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@adminIndex')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('articles/create', 'ArticleController@create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('article/create', 'ArticleController@store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('articles/update/{id}', 'ArticleController@edit')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('articles/update/{id}', 'ArticleController@update')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('articles/destroy/{id}', 'ArticleController@destroy')->middleware('auth');
});
```

Код работает, но не блюдет принципы DRY.

Пробовал делать так:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@adminIndex')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('articles/create', 'ArticleController@create');
    Route::post('article/create', 'ArticleController@store');
    Route::get('articles/update/{id}', 'ArticleController@edit');
    Route::post('articles/update/{id}', 'ArticleController@update');
    Route::get('articles/destroy/{id}', 'ArticleController@destroy');
})->middleware('auth');
```

но получил ошибку

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>
> Call to a member function middleware() on null

Как можно избежать дублирования функции `middleware('auth')` при регистрации нового маршрута с префиксом `admin`?

Comment: Надо указывать так: `Route::middleware('auth')->group(...`. Еще можно в конструкторе контроллера указать `$this->middleware('auth');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как указано в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-middleware):

> To assign middleware to all routes within a group, you may use the
>   middleware method before defining the group. Middleware are executed
>   in the order they are listed in the array:

Т.е. нужно указать сперва middleware, а затем группу маршрутов:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@adminIndex');
    Route::get('articles/create', 'ArticleController@create');
    Route::post('article/create', 'ArticleController@store');
    Route::get('articles/update/{id}', 'ArticleController@edit');
    Route::post('articles/update/{id}', 'ArticleController@update');
    Route::get('articles/destroy/{id}', 'ArticleController@destroy');
});
```

P.S. Почему не используете `Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');`, ведь сами же хотите соблюдать принцип *DRY*?